# What's moving my img to the inside of an unrelated div?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a web page in ASP.NET with C# and bootstrap. I'm trying to change the _Layout. Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - B5 Tours</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerbar">RF Center of Excellence</div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <div style="clear:both;" />
    </div>
    <img src="~/Content/FooterPicture2.png" style="" />

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

note the image, outside the div with classes `container` and `body-content`. However, when I run the website and hit f12 to browse the DOM, and click the image to find it, I see the image inside the `container body-content` div.

```
<div class="container body-content">  
    <div class="col-sm-1 customer-block">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 customer-block">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 customer-block">
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
    <img src="/Content/FooterPicture2.png">

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



    <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
    <script id="__browserLink_initializationData" type="application/json">
        {"appName":"Internet Explorer","requestId":"b2e6b58079644495a5751a037fd16748"}
    </script>
    <script src="http://localhost:63389/a1a3529e4ef74c2e9f1fb2137876c0af/browserLink" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
    <!-- End Browser Link -->
</div>
```

So what gives? Is bootstrap.js moving it? How does it decide what to move? How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an invalid syntax

```
<div style="clear:both;" />
```

According to the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) `<div>` has always end with `</div>`, so the correct would be

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```